# How would I convert this MySQL Data Into This XML String (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

On one of my websites, I am logging all the visitors and their country codes in a MySQL table.

For simplicity, let's just say the columns of this table are "IP" and "Country". So I have a big table of visitors from several different countries.

For display purposes, I need to put this data into an XML format string like this:

```
<set label='US' value='17'/>
<set label='FR' value='12'/>
<set label='GB' value='18'/>
<set label='AU' value='8' />
```

Where **value='' is how many visitors** are from that country. I want the string to include ALL the countries that are in the table.

One way I thought I could do this was to count all the rows with the certain country, for example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE country='US'");
$string.="<set label='US' value='".mysql_num_rows($query)."'/>";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE country='FR'");
$string.="<set label='FR' value='".mysql_num_rows($query)."'/>";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE country='DE'");
$string.="<set label='DE' value='".mysql_num_rows($query)."'/>";
```

The problem, I quickly realized, was that my visitors are from hundreds different countries and this is really messy! Besides, I might miss a country that someone comes from in the future.

Isn't there an easier way to do this? Maybe with a special array and foreach or something...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL query:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) FROM visitors GROUP BY country;
```

The complete PHP section will be:

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT country, COUNT(country) FROM visitors GROUP BY country;" );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) )
{
  echo "<set label='{$row[0]}' value='{$row[1]}'/>";
}
```

Comment: alright thanks...what kinda of output will that give me? Should I convert the query to an array?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT country, count(id) as usercount FROM visitors group by country;");
$fmt = "<set label='%s' value='%s' />\n";
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $string.= sprintf($fmt, $row[0], $row[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS num FROM visitors GROUP BY country");
while (true) {
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
  if (!$row) break;
  $string[]=sprintf('<set label='%s' value='%d'/>',$row['country'],$row['num']);
}
$string=implode("\n",$string);
```